# How to avoid casting when accessing subclass variables from ArrayList of type superclass

Tags: java

```
public void heal() {
    HealingItem hItem = null;
    
    Iterator<Item> it = getInventory().show_inventory().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().getHealing_item() == true) {
            hItem = (HealingItem) it.next();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a parent class Item, and a subclass HealingItem which extends that - for this method I want the player to be able to only access the HealingItem's in the ArrayList of type Item.

Is there a more efficient method of performing this action which perhaps doesn't involve continually casting for these types of issues, or is it even my design which may be faulty?

Thanks

Comment: I would say that this might perhaps be a design problem. What you could do is add a method to the super class that you can call without the need for casting. This could do the check for you. You could add something along the lines of isHealingItem or more generically isOfType(Class<?> class). If true you return if not you don't. Hope this helps.

Comment: You're not storing `it.next()` when you call that if statement, so when you assign `hItem = (HealingItem) it.next();` in the following line, `it.next()` has a different value, and may even throw a NoSuchElementException if you've reached the end of the iterator.

Comment: @JanHaesen I might go with that, thank you!

Comment: @David You're right there, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Java you're stuck with the "ceremony."  To fix your
example per the discussion:

```java
public void heal() {
    Iterator<Item> it = getInventory().show_inventory().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Item item = it.next();
        /*
         * item.getHealing_item() is true
         * implies item is instanceof HealingItem
         */
        if (item.getHealing_item()) {
            HealingItem hItem = (HealingItem) item;
            /*
             * Do something...
             */
        }
    }
}
```

In Java 11 you can reduce some of the ceremony with "var":

```java
public void heal() {
    var it = getInventory().show_inventory().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        var item = it.next();

        if (item instanceof HealingItem) {
            var hItem = (HealingItem) item;
            /*
             * Do something...
             */
        }
    }
}
```

In Java 17 (preview feature as early as 14), you can use "enhanced" instanceof to combine the test with the
cast:

```java
public void heal() {
    var it = getInventory().show_inventory().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        var item = it.next();

        if (item instanceof HealingItem hItem) {
            /*
             * Do something...
             */
        }
    }
}
```